# apt issue - not able to run any apt command

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

Whenever I execute `apt update`  or any other `apt`  command, the process appears to be running in the background, but no output is displayed in the terminal. After some time, the system runs out of memory, resulting in an "out of memory" error. This behavior occurs consistently, regardless of whether I am installing or removing packages.

**Steps Taken So Far:**

1. *Checked system resource usage*: Monitored CPU, memory, and disk utilization using "top" and confirmed that no other processes were consuming excessive resources.
2. *Reviewed system logs*: Examined the system logs using "dmesg" and "journalctl" but found no relevant error messages or warnings related to the `apt`  issue.
3. Verified available disk space: Confirmed that sufficient disk space is available on the system using  `df -h` .
4. Attempted alternative package managers: Tried using "aptitude" and "apt-get" instead of "apt," but encountered the same issue of blank output and high resource utilization.
5. Reinstalled package management tools: Reinstalled the  `apt`  via  `dpkg`  However, the issue persisted even after the reinstallation.
6. Removed all repos and tried using the default `sources.list`

**Additional Information:**

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

System Architecture: x86_64

Kernel: 5.4.0-139-generic
```

Comment: For out-of-memory-related questions, it's a good idea to include the output of `free -h` so we can see the amount of RAM, amount of swap, and the amount of each consumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the contents in `sources.list` and `sources.list.d`. Deleted everything and then used the default `sources.list` from here:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list
```